# RxJava throwing errors

Tags: java, rx-java

```
public Single<User> saveUser(UserRequest userRequest) {
    if(userRepository.findByEmail(userRequest.getEmail())!=null)
        return Single.error(new DuplicateName(userRequest.getEmail()));

    return Single.fromCallable(()->Mapper.mapRequestToUser(userRequest))
        .map(user->userRepository.save(user.blockingGet()));
}
```

I throw my own error-DuplicateName but RxJava wrap it into

```
ERROR 6740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.omg.PortableInterceptor.ORBInitInfoPackage.DuplicateName: IDL:omg.org/PortableInterceptor/ORBInitInfo/DuplicateName:1.0] with root cause

org.omg.PortableInterceptor.ORBInitInfoPackage.DuplicateName: IDL:omg.org/PortableInterceptor/ORBInitInfo/DuplicateName:1.0
```

Why did it happen? I check and if I throw it normally like throw new DuplicateName() works and my global interceptor handles it.

Comment: The question is not clear enough

Comment: Please clarify how the user request is sent to this method and whether we employ concurrent method calls.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `Single.error` doesn't mean throwing an exception - it's rather a terminal event sent downstream saying that something went wrong and this approach is widespread across RxJava.

After such "event" is sent, the `onError` method is called on an observer - and if this method is not implemented - it's wrapped with `OnErrorNotImplementedException`. Provided log doesn't say much, but I think that in your case `onError` can be implemented to just log the exception. That's probably why your interceptor doesn't handle it. You can read more about exception handling in RxJava [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling).

Answer (score 0):

It was my stupid mistake. I have the same error name what 

`import org.omg.PortableInterceptor.ORBInitInfoPackage.DuplicateName;`

and by mistake I import it and didn't notice.....
For others please sure that everything what you imported is from your own packages. Sory folks